# Xcode extension disabled unless I run its app first. Is that how it is supposed to work?

Tags: xcode, xcode-extension

I have created an extension for Xcode.

I have archived the project and created an .app version out of it, using the distribution feature of Xcode. I have created not a notarized version, but one for distribution for my team. I have moved the app to the /Applications folder.

When I run the app that contains the extension, it appears on Xcode.

I quit the app and quit Xcode.

Next time I run Xcode, the extension does not appear on the Editor menu. Again, I have to run the extension app.

Is that how it is supposed to work? I thought the only thing I had to do was to put it in the Applications folder.

Comment: What type of extension?

Comment: what do you mean? My first phrase says "extension for Xcode", this is what it is.

Comment: Oh, you mean -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcodekit/creating_a_source_editor_extension/

Comment: yes, that kind of extension.

Comment: Okay, I've actually been thinking about this a lot, I've only written extensions for iOS. My best guess: you may have to actually push it into TestFlight, and then install it for it to have a normal container+host app relationship.